# PyCharm & Python: Reboot PyQt5 Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, restart

I use this code to reboot a pyqt5 application:

```py
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *['"'+sys.argv[0]+'"', "-t", '2'])
```

The main problem with this command is that after pyqt5 exit on first exit, then i cannot manage the script (stop-debug) from PyCharm.

Any other related command?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can use the subprocess module to restart your PyQt5 application without affecting the debugging capabilities in PyCharm.